# Display result of query without primary key

Tags: sql-server, join

I want to join two tables (each table has 200 columns) so the purpose of this is to have a table with 400 columns, but how do I get the result without the primary key?

```
id  a1  a2  a3 ... a200
-----------------------
1   23  4   5       7 
2   24  6   8       17
3   13  14  52      73
...


 id b1  b2  b3 ... b200
-----------------------
1   53  14  15      87 
2   64  16  18      87
3   73  74  12      83
...
```

So the sesult I want is like

```
a1  a2  a3 ... a200 b1  b2  b3 .... b200 
--------------------------------------
23  4   5       7   53  14  15      87 
24  6   8       17  64  16  18      87
13  14  52      73  73  74  12      83
...
```

I have this

```
SELECT * a as T1 join b as T2 on T1.id=T2.id;
```

Comment: Now you know one reason why 200 columns are not the best idea. Have fun! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to say `SELECT (* EXCEPT some_col)`, sorry. However, it is quite easy to generate the list by dragging the "Columns" node for each table from Object Explorer onto the query window, and then simply remove the PK columns from the list. Click on the Columns node for a view or table, then drag it onto the query window:

[image]

---

Voila!

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to specify each individual column in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT  a1, a2, a3, ..., a200, b1, ..., b200
FROM    T1
        join T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```

Clearly this is overly cumbersome.

I would take a look at why you have so many columns and whether your data is properly normalised.  Alternatively, is there the potential to simply use the columns you need nearer to the UI (if there is one?)